# Как сделать, чтобы nodeJs сервер работал без активированной консоли?

Tags: node.js, сервер, консоль, ssh

Дали пробную неделю на VPS хостинг, поставил там NodeJS, но проблема в том, что он работает, только тогда, когда активирована консоль. Как сделать, чтобы он работал бесконечно?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

С момента последнего ответа прошло уже три года. Node.js существенно "повзрослел" за это время, так что вопрос не потерял своей актуальности.

Думаю стоит упомянуть еще несколько вариантов, которые отсутствуют в других ответах.

**Forever**

В экосистеме Node.js существует пакет [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). Его можно использовать как порождающего демона для вашего приложения. Из плюсов этого решения можно отметить простоту и возможность не писать дополнительный код. Кроме того, можно настроить forever так, чтобы он автоматически перезапускал приложение при его падении. Из минусов -- необходимость тащить в систему node.js скрипт-демон, который нужно устанавливать глобально. В ряде случаев это может оказаться неприемлемым. Запуск приложения, с использованием этого решения выглядит так:

```
forever start app.js
```

а его остановка:

```
forever stop app.js
```

**PM2**

Другим популярным решением из экосистемы Node.js является менеджер процессов [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Как и в случае с forever, pm2 это глобальный установленный node.js процесс-демон (со всеми плюсами и минусами). После его установки запуск приложения осуществляется командой:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

а его остановка:

```
pm2 stop app.js
```

**init.d**

Можно написать обычный [init.d](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) скрипт для вашего приложения. Этот путь используют все нормальные службы Linux. Если говорить о плюсах этого решения, то ваше приложение будет запускаться и останавливаться самой системой, нет необходимости устанавливать лишний процесс демон. Из минусов -- вам перезапускать приложение при падении в ручную (или с помощью специальных утилит). Так же вам придется написать сам init.d скрипт. За основу можно взять, например, [вот это решение](https://github.com/chovy/node-startup). Запуск приложения, с использованием этого решения выглядит так

```
service app-service-name start
```

а его остановка

```
service app-service-name stop
```

Answer (score 13):

Вводите команду так (без **`<>`**):

```
nohup <команда> &
```

---

Завершение:

```
ps -e -o pid,args --forest
```

Ищите **`pid`** (Цифры) напротив вашего процесса, и вводите (без **`<>`**):

```
kill -TERM <pid вашего процесса>
```

Comment: @Zow, да, всё правильно, **`Node.js`** запустился в фоновом режиме, поэтому, игнорирует ввод и весь его вывод сохраняется в файле `nohup.out`, в директории с **`Node.js`**

Comment: @niki-timofе, да все я теперь понял. Я просто запускал с винды через putty, с Убунты все ок

Comment: @niki-timofе, а как теперь отключить этот процесс ?

Comment: @Zow, написал в ответе.

Comment: @niki-timofе, а как перезагрузить )))

Comment: Кстати да, как перезагрузить?))

Answer (score 6):

Все предыдущие ответы очень смахивают на временное решение. Чтобы сделать всё основательно, вам нужно превратить node.js в полноценного демона. Для этого существует набор утилит [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) (не путать с Windows-утилитой для монтирования CD-образов). По сравнению со временными вариантами демон имеет как минимум одно преимущество. Если в ваше отсутствие node.js завалится, то специальный супервайзер сразу это обнаружит и мгновенно его переподнимет.

Comment: @Shamov после установки можно работать через nohup?

Comment: @Zow Можно, но не нужно. Для управления демоном есть специальные команды.

Comment: Другой вариант — написать init-скрипт, на манер такого: [https://gist.github.com/715255](https://gist.github.com/715255). А задачу мониторинга отдать, например, monit'у.

Comment: @Shamov, а есть руководство или примеры специальных команд, тока не на английском. Если нет то могли бы вы написать как запустить и остановить процесс?

Comment: @Zow Руководства на русском я не видел. Я бы мог сказать команды для запуска и остановки. Они простые. Но сами по себе они вам ничего не дадут, поскольку для того, чтобы они работали, нужно предварительно установить и настроить сам daemontools.

Comment: @Shamov, админы установили, но тоже не шарят, как с ним работать. Скажи плиз как запускать и останавливать процесс. http://hashcode.ru/questions/142176/

Comment: node-forever? не, не слышал.

Answer (score 4):

Так-же можно воспользоваться утилитой [`start-stop-daemon`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-stop-daemon).

Запуск:

```
start-stop-daemon -Sbm -p /var/run/nodejs.pid -x node -- some.js
```

Остановка:

```
start-stop-daemon -K -p /var/run/nodejs.pid
```

Answer (score 3):

Выполнить команду screen. При этом откроется уже независимая консоль от ssh соединения.

Чтобы перейти к запущенному ранее скрину, надо выполнить screen -r

Answer (score 1):

Еще 1 вариант - использовать **systemd**, если он есть в вашей системе. Создаем файлик **/usr/lib/systemd/system/[имя_сервиса].service**
Далее в него помещаем конфиг:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=[node binary] [main file]
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=node-sample
User=srv-node-sample
Group=srv-node-sample
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

После этого сделайте симлинк на него:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/[имя_сервиса].service     /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/[имя_сервиса].service`
```

Перезагрузите systemctl:

```
systemctl daemon-reload`
```

И запустите свой сервис:

```
systemctl enable [имя_сервиса].service
systemctl start [имя_сервиса].service
```

Как бонус смотреть логи приложения:

```
journalctl -u [имя_сервиса]
```