# Запуск сервера, написанного на node.js, на хостинге

Tags: node.js, сервер, хостинг

Хотел бы узнать немного информации о том, как работает хостинг и домен, так как не очень разобрался. Ну как я себе представил это - вы покупаете место на удаленном комп'ютере, куда можете заносить свои файлы. Ну допустим я скопирую туда свой проект в виде сайта с сервером написанным на node.js, но до этого я этот сервер запускал только локально, как я смогу запустить его на удаленном компьютере глобально для всего интернета? Спасибо.

код моего приложения:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http').Server(app),
  io = require('socket.io')(http),
  fs = require('fs');
const activeUsers = require('./resources/js/activeUsers'),
  sChat = require('./resources/js/sChat'),
  home = require('./resources/js/home');
app.get('/resources/activeUsers.html', function(req, res){
activeUsers(req, res);
});
app.get('/resources/chat.html', function(req, res){
sChat(req, res);
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
home(req, res);
});
app.use(express.static('resources'));
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
console.log('server is working! '+ this.address().port);
});
//дальше идут запросы от клиента
io.on('connection', function(socket){
```

но в NOW в консоли мне всреавно выводит 4000

Comment: Точно так же, как и локально. Только вместо localhost будет адрес сервера (домен или ip)

Comment: Удалённый и локальный компьютер ничем в этом отношении принципиально не отличаются.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://www.heroku.com/) Можно бесплатно попробовать развернуть свой сервер в интернете, вам даже домен дадут (вернее поддомен вида username-projectname.herokuapps.com )

Comment: тогда мне надо вот в этой строчке:
http.listen(4000, function() {
console.log('server is working!');
});
вписать вместо 4000 имя домена которое дадут?

Comment: @Horchynskyi, нет, там вы должны указать `process.env.PORT || 4000` потому что на heroku порт может меняться при каждом запуске. а в `console.log` добавьте `this.address().port` это покажет вам на каком порте запустился проект. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ukadstun/1/

Comment: а что означает process.env.PORT?
просто я ещё пробую разверуть по похожему методу как в heroku, только на [NOW](https://zeit.co/now), он вроде как удобнее, но у меня само приложение не прогружается, когда уже собирается и работает, вот я и думаю что это из-за того, что не дописал что-то об порте.

Comment: покажите код своего приложения

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы nodeJs сервер работал без активированной консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141042/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-nodejs-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: почитайте документацию как [установить переменные окружения](https://zeit.co/docs/features/configuration#now.json)

Comment: @Horchynskyi, heroku при запуске вашего проекта передаст адрес порта на котором будет готов запустить ваш проект. Адрес для вашего приложения будет доступен в переменной `process.env.PORT` соответственно и соккетами нужно подключаться к нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так к соккетам попробуй подключиться с клиента если используешь heroku или подобное:

```
const socket = io(window.location.host);
```

Comment: спасибо работает, только надо ещё в строку переобразовать) (''+window.location)

Answer (score 2):

Если под хостингом понимать арендованный VDS (он же VPS) - то вы можете зайти на него по протоколу ssh и сделать что угодно. Виртуальный сервер - это почти как обычный компьютер, только с хорошим интернет-каналом и без принудительных межсетевых экранов.

Вот тут расписано как можно настроить node.js на автономную работу без вашего присутствия: [Как сделать, чтобы nodeJs сервер работал без активированной консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141042/178779)

Также выбранный вами хостинг может предоставлять свой особый способ указания команды для запуска сервера. О таких вещах обычно пишут крупными буквами.