# Запуск Node.js скрипта на сервере

Tags: node.js, npm, express

Здравствуйте
Сделал простого ВК бота на *NodeJS*. Запускаю бота через командную строку, например:
 `node bot.js`

Если прервать работу скрипта (Ctrl + C) или закрыть консоль, то соответственно, бот больше не работает.

Нужно чтобы бот работал все время. Есть хостинг, но как сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт запускался на хостинге? Заливал файлы на сервер - скрипт не запускался. Менял название скрипта на *index.js*, тоже не работает.

Comment: Простейший вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/141050/178988 - только я бы сохранил id процесса после запуска, потому что у меня были проблемы с его получением в другой сессии. Ну и ещё куча вариантов в том вопорсе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ссылка на PM2 : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

**Что нужно сделать**

на сервере устанавливаете PM2

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

далее вводите

```
pm2 start bot.js --watch
```

--watch нужен для того чтобы вы не перезагружали js вручную, он сам будет убивать и запускать js

чтобы увидеть все запущенные скрипты

```
pm2 status
```

чтобы увидеть логи

```
pm2 log <ID процесса>
```

ID процесса можно увидеть в pm2 status