# Как выйти из процесса node.js после его запуска через SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Зашел через PuTTy на сервер (Ubuntu 16.02) через SSH, включил нужный мне сервер на node.js. Как выйти из сервера node.js, при этом его не останавливая? Привычные ctrl+c останавливают сервер и выходят в обычное меню.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно запустить сервер в фоновом режиме, а не выходить из него.

Это дубликат вопроса, но как это обозначить - я не знаю. Вот здесь более чем содержательный ответ. Я использовал nohup.

[Как сделать, чтобы nodeJs сервер работал без активированной консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141042/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-nodejs-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)