# Как остановить npm?

Tags: node.js

Я запускаю сайт на node.js на vds хостинге с помощью `npm start server.js`. Все работает, консоль выводит логи, другие могут заходить по ip.

Если нужно перезапустить node, приходится перезагружать весь сервер и заново запускать node. У себя на компе (на windows) я просто закрывал консоль.

Как реализовать остановку и рестарт node из консоли для хостинга?

Comment: Ну, если вы орудуете через putty, то проще всего поставить утилиту screen и работать в ней. По моему чтобы завершить процесс, нужно всего лишь выполнить команду ctrl+c.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы nodeJs сервер работал без активированной консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141042/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-nodejs-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй сочетание кнопок **CTRL + C** чтобы остановить. И научись пользоваться **[screen](http://www.technerium.ru/instrukcii/upravlenie-ekranami-screen-v-centos)**, я скинул тебе мануал как работать с ним в CentOS, но для других ОС тоже есть и использование аналогично, установка немного различна, но суть почти одна и та же.

Создай файл **run.sh** и запускай через него, будет в будущем удобно, особенно когда нормально разберешься.

```
#Путь до проекта
cd /www/test.com/
#Запуск проекта, Test - название процесса
screen -S Test npm run start
```

Скрипт можешь добавить в автозагрузку, тогда сервер будет стартовать сразу же после включения

В packege.json укажи

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node start server.js"
},
```

Если ты во время разработки постоянно перезапускаешь сервер, то можешь воспользоваться **[nodemon](https://monsterlessons.com/project/lessons/perezagruzhaem-node-s-pomoshyu-nodemon)**, он следит за файлами и если, что-то изменилось, то перезапускается

Answer (score 0):

```
$ systemctl list-units // Вывод списка юнитов в памяти systemd
$ sudo systemctl start NAME...
$ sudo systemctl stop NAME...
$ sudo systemctl restart NAME...
```